# \+ with sed doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I'm using Bash and `\\+` works with `grep` but not with `sed`.

For example if I do

```
echo "abbbbc"| sed -e s/ab\\+c/def/
```

I obtain this result : `abbbbc`

I tried with  `'` or with `"`  around `s/ab\\+c/def/`, I obtain the same result.

but if I replace `\\+` with `*`, I obtain : `def`

I have to change `>Atab_TR4682|c0_g1_i1|m.14206` into `Atab`

If I do `echo ">Atab_TR4682|c0_g1_i1|m.14206" | sed -e "s/>*\\([[:alpha:]]\\\*)_.\*/\1/g"`

I obtain `Atab_TR4682|c0_g1` probably because `*` could also be used for 0 iteration, but if I replace `*` by `\\+` it doesn't work at all..

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Use `sed -r` to use extended regular expressions perhaps?

Comment: unable to reproduce iow works fine here - what's your sed version ?; @DopeGhoti - with ERE he'll have to remove the `\ ` before the `+`

Comment: Not without strong quotes he won't (:

Comment: Is your `sed` already aliased to `sed -r` (or `sed -E`) maybe? That would turn `\+` into `+` and vice versa

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: I checked `man sed` and there was no `-E` switch, but there was `-r, --regexp-extended`.  What I meant about the quotes, @don_crissti, is that if not in strong quotes, `bash` will catch the escape before it'll even get to `sed`.

Comment: _Strong_ quotes (`'`) are what I was mentioning.

Comment: @DopeGhoti - yes, without quotes and with a single backslash it will work but as you can see OP is using double backslash...

Comment: @DavidB: What does `sed --version` show at your end ?

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed` accepts an escaped `+`, so if your `sed` is GNU-compatible, you can do:

```
$ echo "abbbbc" | sed 's/ab\+c/def'
def
$ echo "abbbbc" | sed "s/ab\+c/def"
def
$ echo "abbbbc" | sed s/ab\\+c/def
def
```

The POSIX-specified (more generally available) `sed` command only uses POSIX BREs (*basic* regular expressions) by default.  If your `sed` is POSIX-compatible but not GNU-compatible and you want `x+` to act as `xx*`, then you want the `-E` switch:

```
$ echo "abbbbc" | sed -E 's/ab+c/def/'
def
```

Some non-GNU implementations of `sed` include `-r` as a synonym for `-E`, for compatibility with older versions of GNU `sed`.  The `-E` syntax is POSIX, and recent GNU `sed` accept both.

Comment: @don_crissti Edited

Comment: Yes but isn't that (`sed  s/ab\\+c/def`) what the OP claims that it's not working as expected ?

Comment: @don_crissti Yes — my assumption is that their `sed` is non-GNU (mine certainly is)

Comment: Let's see if the OP bothers replying to the comments... Anyway, if their `grep` supports `\+` that means it's a `gnu` setup hence `gnu sed`